# How to register and reference callback interface?

Tags: java, android

When I need a callback from Activity B back to Activity A I usually make the reference variable in Activity B 'static'.  I realize that if the user rotates the device the Life Cycle methods will remove my reference.

Is this the only drawback and is there a better way to register without a static reference. Is it better to simply put all data in the Application class  ? - Thank you.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceMainActivityTwo {
    static Main2Activity main2Activity;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            main2Activity = new Main2Activity();
            main2Activity.setDataListener(this);
    }


        @Override
        public void getDataMainActivityTwo(String string) {
            tvTextData.setText(string);
        }

    }


    public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

        static InterfaceMainActivityTwo mGetDataInterface;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

        public void getDataSaveBtn(View v) {

            if (mGetDataInterface != null)
                mGetDataInterface.getDataMainActivityTwo(fullName);
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "IS NULL.INTERFACE NOT INITIALIZED !!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /////////// interface setup
   interface InterfaceMainActivityTwo  {
        void getDataMainActivityTwo(String string);
    }

    public void setDataListener(InterfaceMainActivityTwo  listener) {
        this.mGetDataInterface = listener;
    }

    }
```

Comment: NEVER use a static reference to an Activity.  Its a guaranteed memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need a callback between two activities.  You're doing something wrong if you do.  If you need to pass data from A to B, pass it in the bundle.  If you need to pass it back from B to A, use startActivityForResult and pass it in the result.  If you need to share data between many activities, it should be held in some globally accessible data structure, either in memory or on disk.

Comment: I have never heard of startActivityForResult. Is the express purpose of startActivityForResult  to get data back to A ? I will google it now.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is.  It allows the second Activity to call setResult() passing it an intent with data (just like when starting an activity).  Then when B is finished, the onActivityResult function of A will be called.

Comment: So what is the primary purpose of an interface ? Because, with fragments it seems to be communication ? At least to a beginner ? Again thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Interfaces have many purposes. An abstract communications channel is one. Ores just not appropriate for use between activities. It is appropriate for use between fragments, or between fragments and activities